# how to find control by name in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, avalonia

i'm trying to find a control by it's name, i tried following the official documentation but i always get an error
this is the code i used

```cs
private void RemoveButton_Clicked(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    userList = this.FindControl<ComboBox>("userList");
    Remove(userList.SelectedItem);
}
```

but i only get an error

```
Could not find parent name scope.
```

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

so this is the solution i found

```cs
private T? FindControlByName<T>(IEnumerable<IVisual> parent, string name) where T : class
{
    foreach (IVisual? child in parent)
    {
        if (child.GetType() == typeof(T) && ((StyledElement)child).Name == name)
            return (T)child;

        // Panel is the base class that contains the `Children` property 
        if (typeof(Panel).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(child.GetType()))
        {
            // recursion :(
            var x = FindControlByName<T>(((Panel)child).GetVisualChildren(), name);
            if (x is not null)
                return x;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

this is a local function and you call it like this:

```cs
// in this example the content of `this` is a grid that's why i'm casting it to a grid
var children = ((Grid)this.Content).GetVisualChildren();

// will search for a ComboBox that's named "userList"
var userList = FindControlByName<ComboBox>(children, "userList");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the axaml add x:Name tag to the control like this:

> x:Name="userList"

after that you can call it in code behind

```
private void RemoveButton_Clicked(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Remove(userList.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, now, but it only works in Avalonia 11+

Answer (score 0):

```cs
ComboBox uL = this.FindNameScope().Find<ComboBox>("userList");
```

Comment: tried and doesn't work
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Avalonia.Styling.dll: 'Value cannot be null.'`

Comment: @cabiste Then you have something else wrong that isn't present in the original issue.  This does work in a minimal example.  In fact I just tried your original method and it works too, so whatever is wrong isn't in the code in the issue.

Comment: the code snippet can be found [here](https://github.com/cabiste69/platform-tools-gui/blob/main/src/PTGUI/MainWindow.cs#L87). 
i also tried the code snippet you posted on the default mvvm template, it worked, but now in the viewModel file. i also think it didn't work for me because my app is c# only no xaml but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Try  `this.GetControl<T>` in your view class.

For instance, I have a `Combobox` control called `x:Name="MyComboboboboBox` in a grid, which is nested in a dock panel, which is nested in some sort of deep tree, I can get the control by

```cs
ComboBox obtainedComboboxControl = this.GetControl<ComboBox>("MyComboboboboBox");
```

in the view class.